# Как правильно задать минимальную ширину Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Необходимо сделать минимальную ширину окна браузера с сайтом `800px` (с внутренними отступами, они вроде по `15px`).

Пробовал задать напрямую, но ничего не получилось:

```
body
{
 min-width: 800px;
}
// и
.container
{
 min-width: 800px;
}
```

Загуглил, говорят, что нужно использовать `Bootstrap 4` `Sass`. Другого способа нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задать `.container { min-width: 800px; }` и будет работать для всех разрешений. 
В bootstrap4 сейчас все намного проще и для `col`:

```css
.container {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><h2>col 1</h2></div>
    <div class="col"><h2>col 2</h2></div>
    <div class="col"><h2>col 3</h2></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"><h2>col 1</h2></div>
    <div class="col"><h2>col 2</h2></div>
    <div class="col"><h2>col 3</h2></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Говорите

> Необходимо сделать минимальную ширину

а свойства задаете для высоты

```
body
{
 min-height: 800px;
}
// и
.container
{
 min-height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Опечатка, не выспался... =) Обновил вопрос.

Comment: нажми стрелку вверх, если помог)